# Database on other Server (MySQL )

Tags: php, mysql

i got a problem while coding my website. I already researched a lot but i really dont know what to do.

```
function getDB() {
$dbHost = 'otherserver';
$db     = 'database';
$dbUser = 'user';
$dbPass = 'blibla';

$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbHost;dbname=$db;charset=utf8mb4", $dbUser, $dbPass);
return $db; }
```

I dont why, but if I try it with localhost it works. If I change my ($dbHost = '123.123.123') MySQL server it dosent. Why? I really got no idea. Please help me.

Comment: is server set up to allow remote host connections? by default most are not

Comment: I would be very careful about allow direct access to your database from the world wide web, databases are very juicy targets, depending on your setup you may want to go with a database web api rather than a direct connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add some error checking to your code, it is quite likely you will get some information that will help you diagnose this problem or at least get an error message that would help someone here understand exactly what is wrong.

So change your code like this and it should generate you a usable error message, when connection is an issue

```
function getDB() 
{
    $dbHost = 'otherserver';
    $dbname = 'database';
    $dbUser = 'user';
    $dbPass = 'blibla';

    try {
        $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbHost;dbname=$dbname", $dbUser , $dbPass );

        /*** set the PDO error mode to exception ***/
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND, "SET NAMES 'utf8mb4'");

    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }
    return $db;
}

$con = getDB();

foreach ($con->query('SHOW TABLES') as $row) {
    print_r( $row );
}
```

Comment: i added it but now i get a new error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'catch' (T_CATCH) in /test/test/webs/test/php/test.php on line 26. mb something on your code wrong?

Comment: } catch (PDOException $e) {

Comment: Ah, it may have been because I used `$db` to hold the database name and also the PDO connection. My mistake, careless. Try the new code. I ran this code using a database I have and it worked

Comment: yes but my script is still not running :( any idea?

Comment: OK as I can access a remote server (on another PC in my network) using that code, the issue must be that you have not created a user account on the remote server that allows said user account to connect from a remote location. What EXACTLY is the error message you get? Also are you sure you are using the correct IP Address in `$dbHost`

Comment: Yes I'm pretty sure its the correct IP Adress cause i specially asked my provider. I dont get an error message (only shows tables), but if i try the script on my vserver with localhost the script works, if i try it on my webspace sadly not.

Comment: So show me how you created the user account on the vserver. Are you sure a) you are allowed to create a user that can connect remotely and b) that you have done that correctly

Comment: yes on my webspace i can tick a box which is called: "allow remote access" on my user/database

Comment: Now I have tested that script against a FastHost server I have a  site on, and that works. I think you will have to check with your hosting company as the issue seems to be with that and not the script

Comment: ok i try to mail them, but i tryed it allready on 3 webspaces and all 3 didnt work... can you may have another option what i can try?

Comment: I am afraid I have nothing else to suggest. Code works when parameters are correct and remote server allows access.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a new MySQL user and grant privileges to allow remote connect to your database.

Something like this:

```
CREATE USER 'user'@'otherserver' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'blibla';
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'user'@'otherserver';
```

Comment: thank you verry much i did everything but i still cant get access to my database. any idea?

Comment: Please, explain a little bit more your situation. You can't get access database from your script, right? Is the database located on another server than script which try to connect to it?

Comment: yes thats right, i can acess with my username, password and hostname on phpmyadmin but if i try to run my script it work only if i select localhost. i dont know why.

Answer (score 1):

On the machine where MySQL is installed you should config remote access. On a linux systems config file located in `/etc/my.ini`.

Open it and find section `[mysqld]`.
Make sure line `skip-networking` is commented (or remove line) and add following line:

```
bind-address = <HERE_YOUR_IP>
```

Restart MySQL server: `/etc/init.d/mysql restart`.

And of course grant access to remote IP address.

```
GRANT ALL ON user.* TO database@'<HERE_YOUR_IP>' IDENTIFIED BY 'blibla';
```

More detailed information look [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html).

Comment: i tryed but still not working i wait for RiggsFolly until he answers my question. still thank you!